# passing hidden variable in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, hidden

I am trying to pass a hidden variable in html form. I set a data and print it and 
later when form is submitted I receive the hidden variable and print it but it does
not print all the values. You can check the output dump at the end. Could you tell me why?

Code

```
function xyz() {
    if ( isset ( $_POST ['modified'] ) ) {
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "template";
        $templateData =  $_POST['templateData'] ;
        echo "------After passing-------------------------<br />";
        var_dump( $templateData );
        echo "------------------------------<br />";
    } else {
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "template";
        $result = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE id='.$item.';';
        $res = $wpdb->get_row ( $result);
        $temp = $res->data ;
        echo "------Before passing-------------------------<br />";
        var_dump($temp);
        echo "-------------------------------<br />";
        // URL for form submit, equals our current page
        $action_url = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
        include_once ('template.html');
    }
}
```

## In file template.html, I am passing a hidden variable $templateData

```
<form action="<?php echo $action_url?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    <?php
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="templateData" value="'.$temp.'">';
    ?>
```

Output:

**Before passing:**

> string(281) "a:21:{i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"1";i:3;s:2:"12";i:4;s:1:"1";i:5;s:1:"1";i:6;s:1:"1";i:7;s:3:"a43";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:5:"title";i:12;s:1:"1";i:13;s:2:"12";i:14;s:1:"1";i:15;s:1:"1";i:16;s:1:"1";i:17;s:3:"a23";i:18;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";i:20;s:0:"";i:21;s:7:"excerpt";}"

**After passing:**

> string(14) "a:21:{i:1;s:1:"

Comment: I saw rawurlencode() works.  Is this good enough or somethink better alternative ??? $data = serialize($data);
$data = rawurlencode($data);

then pass $data through the hidden form field

on the target page:

$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = rawurldecode($data);
$data = unserialize($data);

Comment: You could use `urlencode` like you said. If the field is not too big you could use `base64_encode` also since it does not reproduce any quotes.